# How To Specify nested fields to Wordpress API v2 or Woocommerce Rest API

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm using the Woocommerce REST API in my project and sending a GET request to:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?_fields[]=name&_fields[]=price
```

specifying name and price of products and it works well. But I want to specify some **nested fields**.

while **&_fields[]=images** is included to the url the response is as below, but i want to specify only **"src"** field using above GET request. is there anything to add such as **&_fields[]=images[src]** or something like that?

```
"images": [
        {
            "id": 3611,
            "date_created": "2022-04-10T01:39:14",
            "date_created_gmt": "2022-04-09T16:39:14",
            "date_modified": "2022-04-10T01:39:20",
            "date_modified_gmt": "2022-04-09T16:39:20",
            "src": "https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/APC-0175.jpg",
            "name": "APC-0175",
            "alt": "APC-0175"
        },
        {
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you get to make it work somehow?